# Adding a URL Under a Title Header

Tags: list, url, json, header

I currently have a title header using JSON in a SharePoint list that works as I would like it to. I want to add a URL under the Title which points to a standard operating procedure outlining how to use the list. I need to know how to add the URL code so it will show under the title. See the the yellow highlighted area in the picture below for reference. I used this forum to find the proper code for adding a URL but am unsure of how to put the two together. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Header/Title Code Being Used (this works):

```
{
"elmType": "div",
"attributes": {
    "class": "ms-bgColor-blue"
},
"style": {
    "width": "99%",
    "border-top-width": "0px",
    "border-bottom-width": "1px",
    "border-left-width": "0px",
    "border-right-width": "0px",
    "border-style": "solid",
    "margin-bottom": "16px"
},
"children": [
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
            "display": "flex",
            "box-sizing": "border-box",
            "align-items": "center"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                    "iconName": "HomeVerify",
                    "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regularms-fontColor-neutralLight",
                    "title": "Details"
                },
                "style": {
                    "flex": "none",
                    "padding": "0px",
                    "padding-left": "0px",
                    "height": "36px"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-fontColor-white ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
        },
        "style": {
            "box-sizing": "border-box",
            "width": "100%",
            "text-align": "left",
            "padding": "21px 12px",
            "overflow": "hidden"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "='Used for ticket refund requests ONLY' + [$Title]"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

URL Code (How do I add this to the code above?):

```
{
"elmType": "a",
"txtContent": "Request link here",
"attributes": {
    "href": "[$RequestLink]"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add the URL code to your existing JSON code by adding it as a child element under the main "div" element.

- The URL will be added ***under the title***.
- The URL will be displayed as ***"Request link here"***.
- The URL will link to the URL stored in the `[$RequestLink]` field.
- If your URL is static, please replace `[$RequestLink]` with your actual URL.
- If your URL is dynamic and stored in a SharePoint list column, then ensure the column name matches exactly with `[$RequestLink]`.

Please test and let me know if this helps.

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-blue"
    },
    "style": {
        "width": "99%",
        "border-top-width": "0px",
        "border-bottom-width": "1px",
        "border-left-width": "0px",
        "border-right-width": "0px",
        "border-style": "solid",
        "margin-bottom": "16px"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "align-items": "center"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "HomeVerify",
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regularms-fontColor-neutralLight",
                        "title": "Details"
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "flex": "none",
                        "padding": "0px",
                        "padding-left": "0px",
                        "height": "36px"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-white ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
            },
            "style": {
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "width": "100%",
                "text-align": "left",
                "padding": "21px 12px",
                "overflow": "hidden"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "='Used for ticket refund requests ONLY' + [$Title]"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "txtContent": "Request link here",
            "attributes": {
                "href": "[$RequestLink]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```